# com.android.support:design:27.0.2 what is the last update?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

i'm using `com.android.support:design:27.0.2` for my old project. now i want to update my project. but i'm not understanding what is the `support:design` library for androidx? all dependency is updated, but confused in `com.android.support:design:27.0.2` this.

here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true


        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    // Glide library
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    // Volley library
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    // Recyclerview Library
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.hajiyevelnur92:intentanimation:1.0'
    implementation 'com.sdsmdg.tastytoast:tastytoast:0.1.1'

}
```

please explain what is the new update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of Design support library**,
You can use :
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

Do check for the current stable version

Comment: Yeah, you can see the equivalents in ``androidx`` here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings